# Interpreting Django .update()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to decipher how .update() is being used in this context. Here's the code:

```
 user = User.objects.get(username=username)
 userializer = UserSerializer(user)
 other = Other.objects.get(other=userializer.data['user_id'])
 oserializer = OtherSerializer(other)
 userdata = userializer.data
 userdata.update({'target_id': oserializer['target'].value})
```

And here's the UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_id',
                          'username',
                          'sec_question_1',
                          'sec_answer_1',
                          'sec_question_2',
                          'sec_answer_2',
                          'sec_question_3',
                          'sec_answer_3',
                          'roles')
```

As you can tell, target_id is not in the serializer.

So I am wondering how the original model row is being updated by this .update() method, and I'm wondering where the documentation for it is - is this the QuerySet .update()? Is it the serializer .update() (which doesn't appear to exist - is there a default?)

I'm trying to rewrite this to be more robust and I'm having a hard time understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither of those, and it is not affecting the row at all.

The output of the serializer is a standard Python dictionary. Dicts have an `update` method; that is what is being called here.

That code could just as well have been written:

```
userdata['target_id'] = oserializer['target'].value
```

Comment: That makes so much more sense. I'll accept this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

**The `.update()` used here is not the Django [`QuerySet.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-update) but a  Python dictionary [`.update()`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)**

```
oserializer = OtherSerializer(other) # initialize the serializer with the instance
userdata = userializer.data # get serialized representation of the object
```

The above 2 lines initialize the serializer with the instance. When you do `serializer.data` with an instance passed to it, it will return a dictionary containing the serialized represention of that instance. So `userdata` is a Python dictionary or more precisely an [`OrderedDict`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Now, when you call `.update()` on `userdata` with a dictionary argument, it will add another key `target_id` to the `userdata` dictionary.

The below lines are equivalent.

```
userdata.update({'target_id': oserializer['target'].value})
userdata['target_id'] = oserializer['target'].value
```